# Chef encountered an error attempting to load the node data for "***.***.com"

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I used below URL to start off with Chef.

https://medium.com/@chandra25ms/running-a-chef-cookbook-using-chef-solo-bb4b2773acb8

I installed ChefDK on my windows machine

```
PS C:\Users\bhavek\Desktop\br-test\recipes> chef --v
Chef Development Kit Version: 2.4.17
chef-client version: 13.6.4
```

web.json-

```
    {
     "run_list": [ "recipe[first_cookbook]" ]
}
```

default.rb

```
#
# Cookbook:: br-test
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2018, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

file "C:\br.txt" do
    content "This is my text content"
    action :create
end
```

solo.rb

```
file_cache_path "/home/user/cache"
cookbook_path "C:\DevOps COE"
```

Executed this in ChefDK

```
chef-solo -c "C:\Users\bhavek\Desktop\br-test\solo.rb" -j "C:\Users\bhavek\Desktop\br-test\web.json"
```

Error-

```
PS C:\DevOps COE\first_cookbook> chef-solo -c "C:\Users\bhavek\Desktop\br-test\solo.rb" -j "C:\Users\bhavek\Desktop\br-test\web.json"
Starting Chef Client, version 13.6.4
resolving cookbooks for run list: ["first_cookbook"]
Synchronizing Cookbooks:
  - first_cookbook (0.1.0)
Installing Cookbook Gems:

Running handlers:
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 05 seconds
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/home/user/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to C:/home/user/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] FATAL: Please provide the contents of the stacktrace.out file if you file a bug report
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] FATAL: ArgumentError: different prefix: "C:/" and "/home/user/cache/cookbooks/first_cookbook"
[2018-01-08T18:46:19+05:30] FATAL: ArgumentError: different prefix: "C:/" and "/home/user/cache/cookbooks/first_cookbook"
PS C:\DevOps COE\first_cookbook>
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems, first the cookbook path had to be a path to folder that contains multiple cookbooks, not just a single cookbook like you have there.  Second, you need to create the nodes folder because that is there it will store node data. By default to places it to be relative to the cookbooks path.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Updated latest error logs.

Comment: Please follow our actual tutorial at learn.chef.io instead of whatever out of date blog you are reading.

Comment: @coderanger very helpful. Send new people to a site where each module is, what, 1-2-3-4-5 hours? Instead of just answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

Below are updated Recipe, Solo and web files.

web.json

```
{
 "run_list": [ "recipe[first_cookbook::default]" ]
}
```

solo.rb

```
file_cache_path "C:/DevOpsCOE/cache"
cookbook_path "C:/DevOpsCOE"
```

default.rb

```
#
# Cookbook:: br-test
# Recipe:: default
#
# Copyright:: 2018, The Authors, All Rights Reserved.

    file "C:/br.txt" do
        content "This is my test text content"
        action :create
    end
```

Comment: not everyone will understand the solution if you do not provide some explanations, a good answer always has good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

I was also getting same errors. Updated the knife.rb file with below mentioned variables and it worked:

```
file_cache_path          nil
file_backup_path         nil
```

This is a version specific issue. On another workstation having different chefdk version(older version), same cookbook is working fine.

My workstation version details :

```
C:\chef-starter\chef-repo> chef -v
ChefDK version: 4.9.7
Chef Infra Client version: 15.12.22
Chef InSpec version: 4.21.3
Test Kitchen version: 2.5.2
Foodcritic version: 16.3.0
Cookstyle version: 5.23.0
```